# Вывод результата цикла во внешний массив

Tags: php, веб-программирование, php7

Имеется допусти вот такой php код

```
$data = [
    'Перв.',
    'Втор.',
    'трет.',
    'Четверт.',
    'и тд.',
    ];
    echo '<select>';
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
         echo "<option value='$data[$i]'> $data[$i] </option>" ;
        }
    echo '</select>';
```

Он рабочий, но, допустим, я хочу вывести это из цикла, чтобы просто подставить переменные и это так же работало.
Например:

```
`<form action="" method="GET">
        <select name="select">
        <option value="<?php $data[$i]; ?>"><?php $data[$i]; ?></option>
      </select>
   </form>`
```

Каким образом мне это реализовать? 
Подозреваю, что с помощью функции, но у меня не получается, буду премного благодарен за любую помощь или подсказку.

Comment: Не совсем понятно чего Вы хотите добиться. Просто вывести один элемент, а не несколько?

Comment: вывести список, каждая ячейка option  это 1 элемент массива.

Comment: У Вас же это уже реализовано. Просто хотите это в форму добавить или что?

Comment: И откройте уже для себя дивный мир `foreach`. Запихните цикл в функцию и пользуйтесь на здоровье в любом месте

Answer (score 1):

В общем, чтобы добавить всё это в форму (Каждый элемент массива, что было бы правильно) - Вы можете воспользоваться перебором массива и добавить всё это в форму:

```php
<?php
$data = [
    'Перв.',
    'Втор.',
    'трет.',
    'Четверт.',
    'и тд.',
];
echo '<form action="" method="GET">';
echo '<select>';
foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo "<option value='$item'> $item </option>" ;
}
echo '</select>';
echo '</form>';
```

Если же Вы прям критично хотите перебирать каждый элемент вручную (Что изначально не корректно, так как элементов может быть много), то можете просто использовать индекс:

```php
<?php
$data = [
    'Перв.',
    'Втор.',
    'трет.',
    'Четверт.',
    'и тд.',
];
?>

<form action="" method="GET">
    <select name="select">
        <option value="<?php echo $data[0]; ?>"><?php echo $data[0]; ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $data[1]; ?>"><?php echo $data[1]; ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $data[2]; ?>"><?php echo $data[2]; ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $data[3]; ?>"><?php echo $data[3]; ?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $data[4]; ?>"><?php echo $data[4]; ?></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Но ещё раз напомню, что учитывая, что в данном случае Вы не пользуетесь перебором массива, то и `$i` Вы использовать не можете, так как она будет находиться за пределами функции.

Comment: Минус без причины - признак дурачины...

Comment: Ну потому что `function options() { $data = [...]; $result = ''; foreach ($data as $d) { $result .= '<option value="' .$d .'">' .  $d . '</option>'; }  return $result; }`. Можно ещё проще. Но это для наглядности

Comment: @ArchDemon Во первых `return`, а не `retunr`. А во вторых это изначально не корректный подход записывать так в строку.

Comment: С чего бы это вдруг некорректно в строку писать? По факту мы строку и выводим на экран

Comment: Возможно я не правильно объяснил в общем, я хочу что бы была функция, из которой я могу вывести эти значения,  а не перебирать вручную, что бы в  независимости от количества элементов в массиве, всё выводилось, надеюсь понятно)

Comment: ArchDemon спасибо это  именно  то что я хотел,я был на правильном пути)

Answer (score 0):

```
  function options()
     {  $data = [
        'Перв.',
        'Втор.',
        'трет.',
        'Четверт.',
        'и тд.',
        ];
         $result = ''; 
         foreach ($data as $d)
          { $result .= '<option value="' .$d .'">' . $d . '</option>'; 
        } return $result;
     }
```

Вот собственно примерно то чего я хотел .